# I can't put my emblem of my crew on my car

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-online

I can't put my emblem of my crew on my car:

> Your profile cannot acces user genareted content restriction in privacy settings.

Comment: Does your account have content restrictions on it?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may have to go in and change a few Safety and Privacy settings.

Navigate to My Account page >> Sign in >> Security, family, & forums >> Privacy Settings

From there you will either click "Access to Content" or "Privacy and Online Safety".

Under Content Settings make sure Member Content is marked as "Everyone" to ensure you can see member-created content on Xbox Live. Member content includes images, text, and custom content in games.

There may be a few other settings to try and tweak to see if they are causing the issues. But this is the only one I personally could see causing an issue.

All information was pulled from [this Xbox support page](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/security/xbox-360-online-safety)